# Recommendation for deploying high availability on the presentation side

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, web8, load-balancing

We are currently running SDL Tridion 2013 SP1. We are in the process of upgrading to SDL Web 8 and also deploying High Availability for the Presentation Side (as a completely new setup parallel to the existing production environment).

The website is Java based running off IIS and Tomcat. In the suggested architecture there are 2 web servers running IIS forwarding requests for dynamic contents to 2 Application servers running Tomcat. The same application servers would also be hosting the SDL Web 8 content delivery Discovery and Deployer micro-services.

We suggested running the Discovery and Deployer services in a active/passive fail-over configuration so that the CMS always publishes to only 1 deployer (active at that moment). Both application servers would be communicating with the same Content Broker database. And all published files (JSP, CSS, JS, JPG, etc) would be stored on the filesystem on AppServer1 and then be replicated to AppServer2 using Microsoft DFSR.

In case 1 of the app servers goes down or is offline for maintenance then the the NLB would automatically route all publishing traffic to the other app server (actve/passive fail-over) and publishing would continue seamlessly. As soon as the other server comes back online DFSR would replicate all new/updated files to this server from the other server.

However DFSR requires that both app servers be connected to the domain controller which is a problem for the client's IT Security.

They have asked us to suggest an alternate approach where the CMS can publish to both servers directly and avoid any file replication. If we were to publish to both app servers separately what would be recommended setup?

1. would both app servers be communicating with their own independent Content Broker databases?
2. if one of the app servers goes down (or is taken offline for scheduled maintenance), how would the contents be synced between the two once the server is brought up?

I have read the online SDL documentation ([Content Delivery Presentation Server load balancing](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-5570B671-C4CD-4CC9-943B-489E5390C13E#docid=GUID-A3E4D814-B887-4C59-B2E4-CE405ED2DF32&filename=GUID-A3E4D814-B887-4C59-B2E4-CE405ED2DF32.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A3E4D814-B887-4C59-B2E4-CE405ED2DF32)) but did not find sufficient information.

Kindly advice considering this would be running on SDL Web 8.

Comment: Web 8.5 includes multiple destination publishing and will be out by end of year. Would this be an option?

Comment: What about using a shared filesystem (NAS or SAN) instead of file replication?

Comment: @NunoLinhares Could you please give me some details on how would the below be handled with the multi-destination publishing model of 8.5:

"if one of the app servers goes down (or is taken offline for scheduled maintenance), how would the contents be synced between the two once the server is brought up?"

Comment: Good point, I jumped the gun on that. With DD4T/DXA models this won't be an issue (DB publishing), but for file system it won't work. With multi-destination publishing files won't publish if one target is offline.

Comment: Thanks Nuno. So for physical files based model we would have to stick to some kind of file replication for this to work. Right?